# Laravel 5.4 route::resource update route not working

Tags: forms, laravel-5, routes

The update route is not working.

I have defined route as below

```
Route::resource('contact', 'Dashboard\ContactController');
```

Form action is as below

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'contact.update','role' => 'form', 'class'=>'contact-form','id' => 'contact-form', 'data-submit' => 'noAjax']) !!}
```

I have tried using method as PUT / PATCH but, it still goes to store route.

I tried passing a parameter with update also, but it didn't work

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['contact.update', $list->id]]) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, u need to add hidden _method field and use POST method for the form

> Since HTML forms can't make PUT, PATCH, or DELETE requests, you will
>   need to add a hidden **_method** field to spoof these HTTP verbs. The
>   @method Blade directive can create this field for you:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the resource function, it's generating routes like the following:

```
+----------+-------------------------+----------+-----------------+
|  Method  |          Route          |  Action  |      Name       |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+-----------------+
| GET      | /contact                | index    | contact.index   |
| GET      | /contact/create         | create   | contact.create  |
| POST     | /contact                | store    | contact.store   |
| GET      | /contact/{contact}      | show     | contact.show    |
| GET      | /contact/{contact}/edit | edit     | contact.edit    |
| PUT      | /contact/{contact}      | update   | contact.update  |
| DELETE   | /contact/{contact}      | destroy  | contact.destroy |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+-----------------+
```

As you can see, the `contact.update` is expecting a parameter. So you have to pass an array to the `route` parameter to have both the route's name and it's params:

```
Form::open(['route' => ['contact.update', 'contactId']]);
```

Where `contactId` would be the id of the contact you're trying to update.

Comment: I tried passing the comment as well. But, it still directs to store method    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['contact.update', $list->id]]) !!}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'Dashboard\ContactController');
```

Instead of:

```
Route::resource('contact', 'Dashboard\ContactController');
```